# Run raw mongo command from C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I've tryed running a raw mongo command from C# this is the command that I'm interested to run in C#

```
db.getUser("MyUser")
```

I've tried

```
    public static async Task GetUserInfoAsync(this IMongoDatabase database, string username, string databaseName)
    {
        try
        {
            BsonDocument document = new BsonDocument
            {
                {"usersInfo", new BsonDocument
                    {
                        { "user", username},
                        { "db", databaseName}
                    }
                }
            };

            BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument> command = new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(document);

            var t = await database.RunCommandAsync(command);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

What I get is

ok=1 , users = []

no matter if the users exists or not

Comment: `db.getUser` wraps the _command_ `usersInfo`.

Comment: can you check my updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

Check what you expect to see in the shell, for now it looks like the filter data (about `db`?) you provide is incorrect. Do you see any result without `db` filter? [See](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/usersInfo/) for details. There is no special logic from .net driver here, all what it does is fully the same as `db.getUsers` does in the shell. You may see it in the shell source code:

```
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.getUsers
function(args) {
    var cmdObj = {usersInfo: 1};
    Object.extend(cmdObj, args);
    var res = this.runCommand(cmdObj);
    if (!res.ok) {
        var authSchemaIncompatibleCode = 69;
        if (res.code == authSchemaIncompatibleCode ||
            (res.code == null && res.errmsg == "no such cmd: usersInfo")) {
            // Working with 2.4 schema user data
            return this.system.users.find({}).toArray();
        }

        throw _getErrorWithCode(res, res.errmsg);
    }

    return res.users;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code which uses the command [usersInfo](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/command/usersInfo/).

```
var cmdStr = "{ usersInfo: { user: 'a_user_name', db: 'some_db_name' } }";
var cmd = BsonDocument.Parse(cmdStr);
var result = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017").GetDatabase("test").RunCommand<BsonDocument>(cmd);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```